# Why is all my text uppercased in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to use the text tool in Photoshop, but any text I type in any font (including base fonts such as Arial) is unconditionally uppercased.

I tried to copy-paste a lowercase text, and it gets uppercased as well.

Any idea how to stop me pulling my hair out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deselect the button that automatically capitalises your text in the text panel.

[image: Capital Text Button]